# Cluster of Nginx for scaling

Tags: nginx

Is Nginx intended to be used in a configuration of many Nginx instances so that the load of reverse proxying to many PHP instances is spread out? If so, how is that configured?

Or is it intended that one Nginx instance handles all traffic going to my PHP instances no matter how large the traffic is and that a single Nginx instance can handle all the load?

Answer (score 1):

In short nginx is able to choose different backends, with, for e. g., [ngx_http_upstream_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html), acting as front-end. You can of course use some kind of load-balancing to put several nginx frontends into action, but this doesn't have any special support from nginx PoV.

Answer (score 0):

For example, this configuration spread out proxying to many PHP instances.

```
upstream phpbackend {
    server unix:/tmp/php1.sock;
    server unix:/tmp/php2.sock;
    server unix:/tmp/php3.sock;
    # ... and so on
}

server {

    location ~\.php$ {
        proxy_pass http://phpbackend;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`nginx` can handle some thousand requests if configured well and is a good choice when it comes to static content or proxying something else.
Usually, it would be fairly faster and more performant than `php` or any other dynamic-content backend so it can easily proxy requests for multiple backends.

When it comes to *huge* setups, you would usually setup multiple `nginx` instances, each proxying for a set of backends - assuming most of the site's load is caused by dynamic content.